# Parent-Child relationship query

Tags: soql, query, relationships, childrelationship

Given Account - MaintenancePlan relationship, I have this SOQL:

> SELECT Id, (SELECT id from MaintenancePlans WHERE Id = 'xxxxxxxxpUGAS') FROM Account

Problem is that I just need to get the MaintenacePlans which Id is specified in query, but I get all Accounts of my ORG. So, I need to make a query that just get MaintenancePlan with the ID **'xxxxxxxxpUGAS'**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a where clause in [SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/05/basic-soql-relationship-queries) for Account and use join to filter account record, example:

```
 SELECT 
    Id, 
    (SELECT id from MaintenancePlans WHERE Id = 'xxxxxxxxpUGAS') 
    FROM Account WHERE
    Id IN (SELECT Account__c from MaintenancePlan WHERE Id = 'xxxxxxxxpUGAS')

// Here I assume, Account__c  is field API name and MaintenancePlan  is SObject API Name
```

Comment: You are the best man!! Thank you!